# r1soft agent is failing with the error: "write error while sending code: Broken pipe"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-10.04, r1soft

I have an Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS server with r1soft agent installed in it. Recently, the backups are failing with the following error.

```
--------
write error while sending code: Broken pipe
--------
```

I have reinstalled the buagent but to no avail. On checking the server logs, I could see the following errors listed in it:

```
--------
# tail -f /var/log/messages |grep -i buagent
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: Need to back up 126 sectors
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: (Righteous Backup Linux Agent) 1.79.0 build 12433
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: allowing control from backup server (10.128.136.195) with valid RSA key
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: allowing control from backup server (10.128.136.201) with valid RSA key
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: sending auth challenge for allowed host at (10.128.136.201) port (47890)
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: host (10.128.136.201) port (47890) authentication successful            
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: Backup request accepted.  Starting backup.                              
Nov 17 03:35:06 microscope buagent: Snapshot completed in 0.010 seconds.                                    
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: Error reading blocks from snapshot.                                     
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: Reading blocks failed                                                   
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: error backup aborted                                                    
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: backup failed on agent closing connection                               
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: Backup failed.                                                          
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: write error while sending code: Broken pipe (32)                        
Nov 17 03:45:03 microscope buagent: tell child write failed   
--------
```

I tried changing the 'Timeout' and 'DiskAsPartition' value in '/etc/buagent/agent_config' file but no luck. Also, verified that proper route is added to the backup server. The agent is also running fine.

Am I missing anything? Any help would be much appreciated. 
Note: CDP 2.0 is installed in the backup server.